# pandas: Best way to process multilayer logs?

Tags: python, pandas

For a research project, we are logging keystrokes in a conversational system. Our logs are structured in 3 layers: `conversation` (meta-data about the conversation itself, including users/speakers), `message` (each message within a conversation) and `keystrokes` (each single key that was typed, or removed, with a milliseconds timestamp).

*Sample data:*

```
import pandas as pd

conversations = pd.DataFrame({'convId': [1],
                              'userId': [849]})
messages = pd.DataFrame({'convId': [1,1],
                         'msgId': [1,2],
                         'text': ['Hi!', 'How are you?']})
keystrokes = pd.DataFrame({'msgId': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                           'key': ['H', 'i', '!', 
                                   'H', 'o', 'w', ' '],
                           'time': ['2018-07-13 13:16:56.001', '2018-07-13 13:16:56.354', '2018-07-13 13:16:56.958', 
                                    '2018-07-13 13:17:07.012', '2018-07-13 13:17:07.123', '2018-07-13 13:17:07.653', '2018-07-13 13:17:07.430']})
```

Our goal is to compute various kinds of typing rate measures (e.g. how many letters per minute, but also things such as pauses between words) for each user, in total, per message and per conversation.

Considering our data analysis goal and approach, `pandas` seemed like a logical choice.

However, manipulating 3 related hierarchical dataframes (1 `conversation` ∋ N `messages` ∋ NNN `keystrokes`) isolatedly generates quite a number of complications. E.g., we tried to compute the total time spent to write a message (= last `keystroke.time` - first `keystroke.time` for a determined `message.msgId`), but computing from one dataframe (`keystrokes`) and then populating the other (`messages`) seems already quite complex to do within a vectorized command.

What is the best approach to manage this dataset? I recently learned about [hierarchical indexes and multi-index](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-multi-index): should we then put everything inside a huge single dataframe, with `conversations` and `messages` data repeated multiple times for each single `keystroke` (a kind of "long" format)? Won't it cause many more performance issues (we are looking at thousands of messages and millions of keystrokes)? Or is there a way to do some kind of `dict` of `dict` of `dict`?

Comment: "but computing from one dataframe (keystrokes) and then populating the other (messages) seems already quite complex to do within a vectorized command" not necessarily, merge and groupby are always handy.

Comment: @xyzjayne: so you recommend merging everything into one dataframe and then compute (via groupby) the new variables within this single very long dataframe?

Comment: I'd say keep them separate, and when you need to add a property (message count) to conversation,  for instance, process messages and merge that piece of information into conversation.